# What does the word 'schlanger' mean in Max Max: Fury Road?

Tags: mad-max-fury-road

What does the word "schlanger" mean as used in *Mad Max: Fury Road*. I guess it's an Australian word.

Comment: Please split it on two questions, otherwise it's too broad. Also - why 'paranoic'?

Comment: Well I take that word back not exactly 'paranoic' it should be 'unconventional'. Anyway its a awsome action film from George Miller. Now I want to watch the other 3 movies of Mad Max (Mel Gibsen's)

Comment: @JasonCraig its preferable to separate this two question and ask them separately.

Comment: Click on  [edit] link below the question with relevent information and changes.

Comment: The second part of your question has already been asked here - [What was the silver “valhalla spray” in Fury Road?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/34474/what-was-the-silver-valhalla-spray-in-fury-road?rq=1) - so just edit that part out of the question

Comment: I have removed the second question from your question for the above mentioned reasons.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Schlanger* is an Australian slang term for *dick*, or more anatomically, *penis*.  It is similar to the term *schlong* commonly heard in American English.  It is an *ockerism*, a term associated with the language of *ockers*, those who speak and act in a rough or uncultured way with a Strine, a broad, exaggerated form of the Australian accent.

Comment: S'carn-on cob? Ready for the arvo smoko mate?

Comment: That answer is not correct. I am Australian and have never heard the word Schlanger before Fury Road. No one I know has ever used or heard this term. Schlong on the other hand has been used in Aussie slang, though not so much these days, it was used more in the 70's. Dick is the most common Aussie slang term for penis, also Cock, Prick, Dong, Slug, One Eyed trouser Snake, but not Schlanger definitely not an ockerism.

Comment: @JamieTheBastard Regional variation perhaps?  Or perhaps an older term? My source here was another Australian.

Comment: I've heard the term used in rural NSW and WA as slang for penis. Rural Australians tend to have the more old school vocabulary. Not sure about "smeg" though.

Bonus Trivia: Apparently the Australian accent is one of the better snapshot of the 1800s British accent. The Australian Accent has changed less in the last 200 years than the current British Accent.

The American accent is a snapshot pre 1800 rhetoric English.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhoticity_in_English

Answer (score 0):

Schlange is the german word for Snake. Likely where the Australians got the word from in the first place.

When I watched the film I assumed they meant that, and given they're talking about Max, who is outright seen eating a lizard (raw!) at the start of the film.
I assumed they meant it entirely literally, he's a crazy wastelander who eats snakes. Entirely accurate.

With the added double-entendre that he "eats dick", since she's trying to insult him too.